# Cuda factorial value invalid

Tags: c, cuda

I'm starting to learn CUDA. I wrote program to calculate factorial. Code is working but when i calculate factorial more what 12 i getting wrong values. Why CUDA getting invalid value? How to fix this?
This is my code.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define CUPRINTF cuPrintf

__device__ int silnia(int n)
{
    if (n<2)
        return 1; //silnia z 0 i 1 wynosi 1
    return n*silnia(n - 1);
}
__global__ void kernel(int *a)
{
    *a = silnia(15);
}

int main()
{
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    float elapsedTime;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    int *dev_a,a;
    cudaEventRecord(start);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, sizeof(int));
    kernel << <1, 1 >> >(dev_a);
    cudaMemcpy(&a, dev_a, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime, start, stop);
    printf("Elapsed time : %f ms\n", elapsedTime);
    printf("%d", a);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Thx for help.

Comment: Maybe because 13! doesn't fit in a 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

12 factorial is 479001600 which fits in a `int` variable.

13 factorial is 6227020800 which does not fit in a `int` variable.

If you change `int` to `unsigned long long` (everywhere, including your `printf` format specifier) you'll get some more range, but eventually you will run out of range.

Comment: This is possible to use 64 int in cuda?

Comment: Yes, it's possible with CUDA.

Comment: What is the best calculate time run application on CPU ? t1 = clock();
 cout << "n! = " << silnia(21) << endl;
 t2 = clock();
 float diff((float)t2 - (float)t1); this code always say one but on gpu I getting 0.3 ms

Comment: honestly, performance measurement of a code like this is, in my opinion, not sensible.  You are launching one thread and doing a trivial amount of work.  There are many questions on SO about how to measure elapsed time of code, even some CUDA-specific ones.  If you don't find an answer already, ask a new question.  It's not possible to go through the details of timing measurement in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because there is "overflow". If you continue to use "int" you cannot solve the problem ;)